# ffmpeg mapping to mkv introduces "fake" delay relative to video

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264, mkv

I need to map this x.264 clip into a matroska container using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i f-0.mp4 -c copy f-0.mkv
```

Here is the ffmpeg console output:

```
ffmpeg -i f-0.mp4 -c copy f-0.mkv   
ffmpeg version N-69672-g078be09 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 21.102 / 56. 21.102
  libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5.  9.104 /  5.  9.104
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'f-0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
  Duration: 00:02:08.06, start: 0.005333, bitrate: 5030 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4865 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 7 (4 bytes)
Output #0, matroska, to 'f-0.mkv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 4865 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 7 (4 bytes)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
...
```

The result seems good, playing with well synchronized audio and video. However, MediaInfo shows a new item under Audio (that the original clip didn't have):

```
Delay relative to video                  : 1mn 5s
```

Here is the Mediainfo from the original f-0.mp4 file:

```
Audio
  ID                                       : 2
  Format                                   : AC-3
  Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
  Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
  Format settings, Endianness              : Big
  Codec ID                                 : ac-3
  Duration                                 : 2mn 8s
  Bit rate mode                            : Constant
  Bit rate                                 : 160 Kbps
  Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
  Channel positions                        : Front: L R
  Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
  Bit depth                                : 16 bits
  Compression mode                         : Lossy
  Delay relative to video                  : 67ms
  Stream size                              : 2.44 MiB (3%)
```

Mediainfo from the f-0.mkv output:

```
Audio
  ID                                       : 2
  Format                                   : AC-3
  Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
  Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
  Format settings, Endianness              : Big
  Codec ID                                 : A_AC3
  Duration                                 : 2mn 8s
  Bit rate mode                            : Constant
  Bit rate                                 : 160 Kbps
  Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
  Channel positions                        : Front: L R
  Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
  Bit depth                                : 16 bits
  Compression mode                         : Lossy
  Delay relative to video                  : 1mn 5s
  Stream size                              : 2.44 MiB (3%)
  Default                                  : Yes
  Forced                                   : No
  HANDLER_NAME                             : SoundHandler
```

There is no delay whatsoever and no reason to insert a delay.

I am concerned that this information (Delay relative to video) be used by some players or other applications as a delay that should be corrected. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Adding ffprobe output: f-0.mp4 clip

```
ffprobe -show_entries stream=codec_type,duration,start_time -of compact f-0.mp4
    ffprobe version N-69672-g078be09 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
    configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
    libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
    libavcodec     56. 21.102 / 56. 21.102
    libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
    libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
    libavfilter     5.  9.104 /  5.  9.104
    libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
    libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
    libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
  Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'f-0.mp4':
    Metadata:
      major_brand     : isom
      minor_version   : 512
      compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
      encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
    Duration: 00:02:08.06, start: 0.005333, bitrate: 5030 kb/s
      Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4865 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
      Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
      Side data:
        unknown side data type 7 (4 bytes)
  stream|codec_type=video|start_time=0.000000|duration=128.061267
  stream|codec_type=audio|start_time=-0.005333|duration=128.064000
```

f-0.mkv clip:

```
ffprobe version N-69672-g078be09 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 21.102 / 56. 21.102
  libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5.  9.104 /  5.  9.104
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'f-0.mkv':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: isomiso2avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : isom
    MINOR_VERSION   : 512
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.19.100
  Duration: 00:02:08.13, start: 0.061000, bitrate: 5026 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      LANGUAGE        : und
      HANDLER_NAME    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      LANGUAGE        : und
      HANDLER_NAME    : SoundHandler
stream|codec_type=video|start_time=0.066000|duration=N/A
stream|codec_type=audio|start_time=0.061000|duration=N/A
```

Comment: Run `ffprobe -show_entries stream=codec_type,duration,start_time -of compact f-0.mp4` and same for the MKV. What do they say?

Comment: Added the ffprobe output in main post. (I don't see anything related to an audio delay)

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a primary attribute stored in the file, but an interpretation, a quirky one, by Mediainfo.  If it plays OK in a few different players, I wouldn't be bothered.

Comment: I think it actually created an issue when I used the file in multiAVCHD to author an AVCHD disc and the app delayed the audio by the exact amount of 65 sec.  It was actually easy to fix by setting the audio delay to zero.  Looks like a weird Mediainfo bug.  Thanks for looking at it.